# how can I ensure a user will not delete another user object in my website [Django]

Tags: django, forms, model, django-urls

I wrote a function that allows the user to delete his article on a blog website. The problem is, if he plays a little with the url, he can access to another article and delete it.

What is the common strategy to avoid such cases with django?

here are the codes I wrote for the fonction:

views.py

```
def delete_article(request, id):
    deleted = False
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request) #that line allow to ensure that the user is connected. I use the session to achieve that instead of extending the User model
    offer = get_object_or_404(Offer, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offer.delete()
        deleted = True
    return render(request, 'offers/delete_article.html', locals())
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('article.views',
    url(r'^send_article$', 'send_article', name='send_article'),
    url(r'^my_articles$', 'show_my_articles', name='my_articles'),
    url(r'^article/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'read', name='read'),
    url(r'^articles$', 'show_articles', name='articles'),
    url(r'^search_article$', 'search', name='search'),
    url(r'^delete_article/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'delete_offer', name='delete_offer'),
)
```

delete_article.html

```
{% if not deleted %}
Hey, are you sure you want to delete {{ article.title }}?
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" class="deleting_offer_button">delete</button>
</form>

{% elif deleted %}

<p>the article was successfully deleted</p>
<a href="/">get back to the homepage</a><br />

{% endif %}
```

As you can see, if the user change the numer of the id in the url, he can delete other article when he is directed to the confirmation of deleting page.

What webmasters are doing to ensure users cannot interfere with objects of other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpResponseForbidden](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden) can be used here which uses a 403 status code. A  403 response generally used when authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.

Assuming you have author as an foreign key in Offer model, you can change your views like this:

In your views.py you have to import :
`from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden`

And then in your delete_article method use this code

`offer = get_object_or_404(Offer, id=id) 
 if offer.author != request.user: 
    return HttpResponseForbidden()`

Answer (score 1):

When you get the article/offer. Make sure that the owner of that article is the authenticated user.

I'm not sure what your models look like but it would be something like

```
offer = get_object_or_404(Offer, id=id, author=logged_user)
```

This way if they don't own the article, it will 404

Comment: thank you. I followed the way of gaurav because it is more explicit and I like when it's very clear but your way is working perfectly too :)